# Vmcom и vmlim debian

Tags: сервер, ssh, debian

Почему так происходит, что vmcom превышает vmlim? Как-то можно увеличить значение vmlim?

[image]

Comment: а что такое vmcom?

Comment: @dimka3210, самому хотелось бы знать. Видимо, как-то связано с жёсткими дисками. Но из-за этого превышающего vmcom сайт тормозить начинает.

Comment: Из [man atop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/atop)

    SWP
    Swap occupation and overcommit info.
    ...
    ... the committed virtual memory space ('vmcom') ... is the reserved virtual space for all allocations of private memory space for processes. The kernel only verifies whether the committed space exceeds the limit if strict overcommit handling is configured (vm.overcommit_memory is 2). 


Подробнее о памяти см. ссылку в ответе @Влад Дяченко

Comment: Вообще-то (IMHO) у Вас swap маловат. [Почитайте здесь](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочешь узнать подробнее:
http://careers.directi.com/display/tu/Understanding+and+optimizing+Memory+utilization

А вообще это SWP, т.е. SWAP – это специальный раздел на диске или файл, в который операционная система перемещает отдельные блоки оперативной памяти в случае, когда оперативной памяти не хватает для работы приложений. Свободных у тебя 11.4 G, так что тормозить сайт может, только если какой-то твой скрипт сжирает всю память. Увеличить размер SWAP можно, но настоятельно не рекомендуется это делать. Лучше оптимизируй скрипты или узнай, что сжирает всю память на сервере. И красную линию можешь смело игнорить.

Comment: @Влад Дяченко, увеличил размер SWAP пока. А можно узнать, почему не рекомендуется его увеличивать?

Comment: Использование swap как расширителя оперативной памяти значительно замедляет работу компьютера.
Я, к сожалению, не системный администратор, но читал об этом, и очень многие не рекомендуют увеличивать SWAP. Лучше сделайте увеличение SWAP "на лету":

http://ubuntulogy.org/docs/fs/3259